# Django channels and asynchoronise system

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, chatbot, django-channels

How does Django Channels facilitate real-time communication in chat systems, and what are the key components involved in its operation? Additionally, could you elaborate on how Django Channels enables asynchronous communication between two devices in a chat system, highlighting its mechanisms for handling WebSocket connections, message routing, and consumer processing?